# How can I view a repo shared with me?

Tags: github

I'm a full stack developer currently working on a few different collaborative projects via GitHub. Is there a way to view projects shared with you by others instead of searching for the repo owner's name/starring the repo?

One of my team members has suggested starring the repo in order to view them but I am wondering if there's a way to set up GitHub so that any repos shared with you can automatically be sorted. Like how Google Drive has a 'shared with me' section.